# How to merge two sql tables where B is a subset of A and should override A?

Tags: mysql

Table A (nothing is unique)

```
╔══════╦══════╦═══════════╦═══════════════╗
║ p_id ║ l_id ║  p_name   ║ p_description ║
╠══════╬══════╬═══════════╬═══════════════╣
║  212 ║    1 ║ Ball      ║ Red           ║
║  212 ║    2 ║ Balle     ║ Rouge         ║
║  301 ║    1 ║ Horn name ║ Blue          ║
╚══════╩══════╩═══════════╩═══════════════╝
```

Table B (p_id is unique)

```
╔══════╗
║ p_id ║
╠══════╣
║  101 ║
║  201 ║
║  210 ║
║  212 ║
║  234 ║
║  250 ║
║  301 ║
║  320 ║
╚══════╝
```

W.r.t p_id, Table A is a subset of Table B (all p_id should exist in Table B) but Table A contains different data.  Both tables contain a lot more columns that I'm not showing.  For table A I'm only concerned with the p_id.  For table B I want to eliminate duplicates based on l_id.  There will always be an entry with l_id of 1 but there may or may not be others which should be discarded (ie. a simple WHERE l_id=1 should do).

The result should be a table that has every p_id of Table B (once) with every column of Table A.  Most of the rows will have no data in those other columns, because they didn't exist in Table B.  So I should have this, for example:

```
╔══════╦══════╦═══════════╦═══════════════╗
║ p_id ║ l_id ║  p_name   ║ p_description ║
╠══════╬══════╬═══════════╬═══════════════╣
║  101 ║      ║           ║               ║
║  201 ║      ║           ║               ║
║  210 ║      ║           ║               ║
║  212 ║    1 ║ Ball      ║ Red           ║
║  234 ║      ║           ║               ║
║  250 ║      ║           ║               ║
║  301 ║    1 ║ Horn name ║ Blue          ║
║  320 ║      ║           ║               ║
╚══════╩══════╩═══════════╩═══════════════╝
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, this sounds like a `left join`:

```
select b.p_id, a.l_id, a.p_name, a.p_description
from b left join
     a
     on b.p_id = a.p_id and a.l_id = 1;
```

Comment: I think the output of your code will be just 2 rows while he need to 8 rows. **Edit:** your condition is `b.p_id = a.p_id and a.l_id = 1`, then I think so.

Comment: @stack . . . Why would you think that?  It will return all the rows in `b`, and I think there are eight of those.

Comment: I know that you right *(for the number of your rep)* , but I don't know why ?! look, when you use `join` there is a condition `on`. now there is just two rows that are true in your condition. let me ask one thing. what happen If I change the place of `a` and `b` in join ?! something like this: `from a left join b`

Comment: @stack . . . A `left join` keeps all rows in the first first table, regardless of whether the `on` condition evaluates to true or false.

Comment: oh, really ?! cool. just tell me if you use `inner join` instead of `left join`, then the output will be just two rows ?

Comment: @stack . . . With an `inner join`, there would only be two rows.

Comment: Thank you to clarify for me. by the way in my opinion you can add this to your solution: `order by b.p_id`

Comment: Weird... that's the first thing I tried!  But I didn't get the results I wanted, so I figured a simple LJ wasn't correct.  I obviously typed something wrong because now it works, as you well know.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To get all rows from one table and the rows matching some condition from another you can use a `left join`:

```
select b.p_id, a.l_id, a.p_name, a.p_description
from b
left join a on b.p_id = a.p_id and a.l_id = 1
```

This will get you everything from B with values for the columns in A matching the where condition. For those rows in B that doesn't have any matches you'll get `null` values.